# USB Mouse and Keybpard stop working when USB hard drive is plugged in

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, mouse, hardware-failure

I have an HP Pavilion Model 13 laptop running windows 10, and use an HP wireless USB Mouse/keyboard combo.  I have a USB connected Seagate FreeAgent GoFlex 2TB external hard drive.  I have been using the hard drive for a couple of days with no problem, but now when I plug in the external drive (not downloading, or even opening, files, just plugging it into the USB port), the wireless mouse/keyboard stop working.  As soon as I unplug it, they work again.

There are only 2 USB ports--I have tried switching which port each is plugged into, with the same result.

I have just checked that all of the drivers are current for hard drive, USB ports, mouse, and keyboard.

Windows Update is current.

Any help/suggestions y'all can throw my way would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working usb port left get an [external at least 2amp ac powered usb hub.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HMZSRS7) Usb ports are prone to failure and are under-powered.

Comment: Both ports work, it's just that when the drive is connected, the mouse doesn't. But when I unplug it, the mouse works again.

From what you're saying, though, it may have something to do with the amount of power the drive is pulling? So, I ordered what you linked to, hopefully that will solve the problem! Thanks, I'll keep ya posted